# Why doesn't Rust let me compare a Foo and an &Foo?

Tags: rust, reference, equality

As far as I understand, equality comparison between references compares the values of the referents, not the addresses contained in the references.  i.e. They implicitly dereference the references.

This being the case, why do I need to write:

```
if ref_to_foo == &another_foo {
```

rather than

```
if ref_to_foo == another_foo {
```

when

```
if ref_to_foo == ref_to_another_foo {
```

already has both sides implicitly dereferenced?

The obvious answer is "because the compiler makes me", but I'm trying to understand why the language designers considered this to be a bad idea.

Comment: In the first example, are you sure it's not `if ref_to_foo == &another_foo {`? (I cannot compile your formulation)

Comment: @prog-fh You're right, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When writing `a==b`, the compiler understands `PartialEq::eq(&a, &b)`.

Thus, when writing `&a==&b`, the compiler understands `PartialEq::eq(&&a, &&b)`.

[This documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%26%27_%20B%3E) leads to this source code

```
    impl<A: ?Sized, B: ?Sized> PartialEq<&B> for &A
    where
        A: PartialEq<B>,
    {
        #[inline]
        fn eq(&self, other: &&B) -> bool {
            PartialEq::eq(*self, *other)
        }
        #[inline]
        fn ne(&self, other: &&B) -> bool {
            PartialEq::ne(*self, *other)
        }
    }
```

showing that the implementation of `PartialEq::eq(&&a, &&b)` simply dereferences the arguments in order to forward the call to `PartialEq::eq(&a, &b)` (so, the same as `a==b` in the end).

There does not seem to exist any default implementation of `PartialEq` that dereferences only one of the two arguments, thus `a==&b` and `&a==b` should be rejected.

Comment: I think the question is is there some _reason_ why the language doesn't treat this case (comparing references to non-references) specially in order to improve ergonomy of use, like it treats various other things, such as auto-dereferencing in function calls. A reason like a bad interaction with other language features, or it being hard or impossible to implement due to a limitation in the compiler, etc.

Comment: It is related to trait coherence and how it currently works. See: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1332

Comment: @darksv That issue shows why this feature cannot be provided by a blanket implementation. It doesn't show why the compiler couldn't insert a `&` to the non-reference when comparing a reference with a non-reference (of course, only if that would allow `==` to compile). The compiler does similar things already, for example if `v` is a `Vec<u32>`, you don't need to type `(&mut v).push(0)` just because `Vec::push` accepts a `&mut Vec`. `v.push(0)` works and the compiler behaves _as if_ you wrote the borrow.