# Why comparing &str-s, String-s, &String-s, &i32-s with the same value results equal, even though the instances are different?

Tags: rust

```rs
fn main() {
    let v1 = 5;
    let v2 = 5;
    let mut s = String::new();
    s.push_str("a");
    println!("{}", "a" == "a");
    println!("{}", String::from("a") == String::from("a"));
    println!("{}", String::from("a") == s);
    println!("{}", &String::from("a") == &s);
    println!("{}", &v1 == &v2);
}
```

Why does comparing different String instances, or even references to different String instances, (that though have the same value) results equal? Those are different pointers to even different locations (because the instances are different), aren't they?

Comment: As explained in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641043/11527076), Rust dereferences before the comparison, then compares the values.

Comment: "Those are different pointers to even different locations (because the instances are different), aren't they?" Which is completely irrelevant. Pointer comparison is pretty much never what you want, so it's not what is implemented. Rust comparison is implemented through various traits (`PartialEq`, `Eq`, `PartialOrd` and `Ord`), and one can implement those however they want. The preferred semantic for implementing the comparison trait is value comparison, because this is the useful one, in particular references comparison dereferences the values before comparing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you read `&v1 == &v2` as in C, but in Rust this is different.
Rust does not compare the references (addresses in C), but the values behind the references.

The previous expression is similar to `*(&v1) == *(&v2)`; the comparison through references ([`impl<A: ?Sized, B: ?Sized> PartialEq<&B> for &A where A: PartialEq<B>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%26%27_%20B%3E)) is just a convenience.
For example, if `r1` and `r2` are references, then `r1 == r2` is easier to read/write than `*r1 == *r2` but it performs the same comparison.

Comment: There is no "automatic" dereference, just an impl of `PartialEq<&B> for &A where A: PartialEq<B>`. See my answer.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman You are right; I remember now that I wrote [something about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68234367/11527076) a few months ago. I rephrased in order to remove this badly chosen terminology. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rust allows you to overload operators by implementing traits. `==` and `!=` are also overloadable. You need to implement the [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) trait for that: the expression `x == y` translates into `PartialEq::eq(&x, &y)`, and `x != y` translates into `PartialEq::ne(&x, &y)` (note that `PartialEq` has a default implementation for `ne()` that calls `eq()` and reverses the result, so you only need to implement `eq()` manually).

If you'll enter [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c50c752becf7d339a2848314b9ae70eb) where I simplified your example to remove the prints, and select "Show MIR" from the menu, you'll get the following (simplified):

```rust
// let v1 = 5;
let _1: i32 = const 5_i32;

// let v2 = 5;
let _2: i32 = const 5_i32;

// let mut s = String::new();
let mut _3: std::string::String = String::new();

// s.push_str("a");
let _5: &mut std::string::String = &mut _3;
let _7: &str = const "a";
let _6: &str = _7;
String::push_str(_5, _6);

// "a" == "a";
let _32: &&str = &const "a";
let _31: &&str = &const "a";
let _8: bool = <&str as PartialEq>::eq(_32, _31);

// String::from("a") == String::from("a);
let _13: std::string::String = <String as From<&str>>::from(const "a");
let _12: &std::string::String = &_13;
let _15: std::string::String = <String as From<&str>>::from(const "a");
let _14: &std::string::String = &_15;
let _11: bool = <String as PartialEq>::eq(_12, _14);

// String::from("a") == s;
let _18: std::string::String = <String as From<&str>>::from(const "a");
let _17: &std::string::String = &_18;
let _19: &std::string::String = &_3;
let _16: bool = <String as PartialEq>::eq(_17, _19);

// &String::from("a") == &s;
let _23: std::string::String = <String as From<&str>>::from(const "a");
let _22: &std::string::String = &_23;
let _21: &&std::string::String = &_22;
let _25: &std::string::String = &_3;
let _24: &&std::string::String = &_25;
let _20: bool = <&String as PartialEq>::eq(_21, _24);

// &v1 == &v2;
let _28: &i32 = &_1;
let _27: &&i32 = &_28;
let _30: &i32 = &_2;
let _29: &&i32 = &_30;
let _26: bool = <&i32 as PartialEq>::eq(move _27, move _29);

return;
```

Both [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3CString%3E), [`str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3Cstr%3E) and [`i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3Ci32%3E) has an implementation of `PartialEq` (note that the compiler has built-in knowledge about integer types, so `i32` is not usually compared with `PartialEq` but with intrinsic instruction, but it is required for generics). This is how all of stuff like `String::from("a") == String::from("a")` or `*"a" == *"a"` work - it calls `<String as PartialEq>::eq()` and `<str as PartialEq>::eq()` accordingly.

There are also bunch of impls for the various combinations of `str` and `String`: e.g. [`String == str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3Cstr%3E-4), [`String == &str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%26%27a%20str%3E) or [`str == String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3CString%3E-3).

Lastly, there are four generic impls of `PartialEq`: [`&A == &B`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%26%27_%20B%3E), [`&mut A == &mut B`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%26%27_%20mut%20B%3E-1), [`&A == &mut B`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%26%27_%20mut%20B%3E) and [`&mut A == &B`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%26%27_%20B%3E-1), all where `A: PartialEq<B>`, that allows you to write things like `&&&"a" == &&&"a"` or `&v1 == &v2`, in your example.

Last note, there is also [impls for pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3C*const%20T%3E), that compares addresses, like you expected. So, while `&String::from("a") == &String::from("a")`, `&String::from("a") as *const String != &String::from("a") as *const String`. There is also a function [`std::ptr::eq()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/fn.eq.html) that makes it convenience: `!std::ptr::eq(&String::from("a"), &String::from("a"))`.